# VueJs - Element UI : How to change active class el-radio

Tags: list, vuejs2, radio-button, element-ui

I want to change li class when el-radio is clicked become active class list, and when the active background class list is blue.

here is my code:

```
ul class="list-class">
    <li v-for="(item, index) in dataList" :key="index">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
          <el-radio v-model="radio" :label="item.id">
            <span></span>
          </el-radio>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
          {{ item.name }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

and here my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dede402/38mn5y9q/

Answer (score 0):

add `:class="{'active':radio===item.id}"` to the v-for iterator

```
  <template>
      <ul class="list-class">
        <li v-for="(item, index) in dataList" :key="index" :class="{'active':radio===item.id}">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <el-radio v-model="radio" :label="item.id">
                <span></span>
              </el-radio>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
              {{ item.name }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <pre class="pre-item">radio = {{ radio }}</pre>
  </template>
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/38mn5y9q/4/